# what does XBIM used for triangular mesh boolean operation?

Tags: ifc

XBIM provides a library for serializing/deserializing IFC file.

At some point they must have used mesh boolean operations.

I wanna know what library they have used and how they have created openings in IfcWall standard case?

Answer (score 2):

Xbim primarily uses the [OpenCascade](https://www.opencascade.com/) library for cutting openings, and other boolean operations. However, as a performance optimisation [Carve CSG](https://code.google.com/archive/p/carve/) can be used for some operations (enabled with a conditional compilation switch).

3rd party libraries are credited in the Xbim.Geometry [Readme](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/blob/master/README.md) in the github repo

That Xbim.Geometry.Engine project in the same repo demonstrates how to perform cuts in Geometry using OpenCascade and CarveCSG, although it gets [pretty involved](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/blob/master/Xbim.Geometry.Engine/XbimSolid.cpp#L1235).